# Webcrypto API - How to provide array buffers ( signature and public key ) as strings?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cryptography, webcrypto-api, webcrypto

I'm using the Webcrypto API to sign data and now have the public key and signature both of type `ArrayBuffer`. Both information should be stored into separate files, so

- the public key should be stored as a string into a "public_key" file
- the signature should be stored as a string into a "signature" file

I'm new to this and don't know the "easiest" file formats so other languages/packages ( e.g. Java backends ) can deal with the files.

For the public key the SPKI format as a PEM string looks fine? But I don't know an approach for the signature. I started with the following

( [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUzAgTgQygg0ggngBTQEsUYBeGNCXMYGAMwFdaojwAKAShgG8BYAFAxhMFAiiMUYGMBS4ADlBAA6CIwBGUADYJliZOkw5c7QSPO8zF62DQBbBAC4YAIgCiAYQAiAZQCCLgA0Vtbmtg4AJh6SAG5OrvgAtADMABwALEEhFgC%20wUKhUCiMCPmhMADaLhBEcGBBrnEoRPS4LgC62ZwA3II5vQKCoJCwNXXklNS0DMzArBzyzTEY2HjOHnKKIMaBMOqM9PSozgBCB0coPiCSwAjc-AXCYhJSMptKqhraumNg7A82ezxRZEZZGPDKNBaOAgZpQAAWdmU4VK2WE8Ko8OcAHIfAAJPyJACsAEYAEzY7J5GAgsGrXC7faHVA9PoDIbgaAwBAAD3ksKgxj8EB8%20CwAEkJlQaHQmCw2H9ZAolMZ1u9tnh7tlnpJpEqtp9NDplLz%20ShBXh2NV5ABrIgNfUqzVswQckYwCC2ogAFRA%20DcAFkJnK5gr2EyLs4-Ch0LgzsyUFrHjJObAqD4ikQwHAJhnmtnlPQUCA7B4MSgPCAIro0PJ5FoTGBGFotLtkAB3GAAVSzUFS0dj4fOLNZyeGXKoJyoCAAbOkJpoQGh2OnM9nR%20ZteJdTAAAaJA8Hk5uADi4oAcjB8F2TgAZcUeGBYNwATUPB4AOmAACQ8SfTucci-d9Ejcc8vCvG970fZ833fXcBn6V0BBXKY6C4cgAD5LGTAB6XCYBPJBUBWGAbTwCAYGybJx1gHgaSWFYdhpDQtCIYBjBgHIpXbYhYH0EjwQIYgUC4dk8IInxamkCIMDQZDzFomBZKgNAJno%20gQBAHF1DQFBsS4gZFNTD01zgFoiAQCIvDkiYACkfAAeXPVQzJaEwVLQDcRCUiNUAmDsYG9XkoDcWgq1QLgTXC6t2GgfNzPoSzrLk7zhBokzfgwSQEB4viPWk9haSYvBGWHRNxPMfCYErMAmlgeRWPYsi8BgJRTIStqQFM2Fct7bqkp0BSfJMxr1DYji8GFUUJQAMVhOwMDyohYFNAUhRFMVxSKprJtwNKU3deQEDsMLQGrCJOIoT07V9f0Ax28b2I2mbxXmlBFqgUdsmq2r6oKupsrELqOqzHN2ugXqYH6hgiCGwYJJgZRkaCxyvEcpHkeG4RqvR883Gxw6IBAY0tBAOArXwXaWtwRwXAO8cSd0MmKeO06Yqs4xvrHTkmeUFmrSkwGXicemjJGyA%20YFlwlAiFRkbFvpODEoA) )

```
const generateKeyPair = async function() {
    return crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        {
            name: "ECDSA",
            namedCurve: "P-384",
        },
        true,
        ["sign", "verify"]
    );
};

const sign = async function(privateKey: CryptoKey, buffer: BufferSource) {
    return crypto.subtle.sign({
      name: privateKey.algorithm.name,
      hash: 'SHA-512'
    }, privateKey, buffer);
};

const exportKeyAsSPKI = async function(cryptoKey: CryptoKey) {
    return crypto.subtle.exportKey("spki", cryptoKey)
};

const spkiToPEM = function(buffer: ArrayBuffer) {
    const asString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buffer));
    const asBase64 = btoa(asString);
    
    return `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n${asBase64}\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;
};

(async () => {
    // Generate keys 
    
    const { privateKey, publicKey } = await generateKeyPair();

    // Sign data

    const data = { foo: 'bar' };
    const stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(data);
    const buffer = new TextEncoder().encode(stringifiedData);
    
    const signature = await sign(privateKey, buffer);

    // Convert public key to string to store into file

    const publicKeyAsSPKIFormat = await exportKeyAsSPKI(publicKey);
    const pemEncodedKey = spkiToPEM(publicKeyAsSPKIFormat);

    // Convert signature to string to store into file

    // ... TODO ...

    // DONE

    console.log("Public key:");
    console.log(pemEncodedKey);

    console.log("Signature:");
    console.log("todo...");
})();
```

What is the approach for the signature? Are there any better approaches for the public key?

Comment: Libraries use different formats/encodings, so there is no *best* choice. The most reasonable way is to use one of the supported formats/encodings of the WebCrypto API and convert the data afterwards if required (especially since the WebCrypto API has little conversion support).

Comment: WebCrypto API uses IEEE P1363 as ECDSA signature format. If the signature is to be stored as string, apply a binary-to-text encoding, e.g. Base64. For completeness: Another common ECDSA signature format is ASN.1/DER, s. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/57731/ecdsa-signature-rs-to-asn1-der-encoding-question).

Comment: Regarding the exported PEM key: The body of a PEM encoded key generally contains line breaks after every 64 characters, which is missing in your implementation.

Comment: @Topaco to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75958818/webcrypto-api-how-to-provide-array-buffers-signature-and-public-key-as-str?noredirect=1#comment133975608_75958818 - are there any native implementations? Otherweise I think using a Base64 string is way easier, no?

Comment: @Topaco to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75958818/webcrypto-api-how-to-provide-array-buffers-signature-and-public-key-as-str?noredirect=1#comment133975643_75958818 this implementation is not correct yet but I guess you mean something like this www.shorturl.at/xKL17

Comment: The ASN.1/DER ECDSA signature format is not supported by WebCrypto (neither can this be specified as output format nor are there conversion functions), i.e. this must be implemented by yourself or another library must be applied for this (e.g. [here](https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/api/symbols/KJUR.crypto.ECDSA.html#.concatSigToASN1Sig)).